# Tensor product of hyperplane arrangements

Tags: co.combinatorics, hyperplane-arrangements

Let $(A_{1},V_{1})$ and $(A_{2},V_{2})$ be two central hyperplane arrangements, which 0 belongs to their intersections. Let $V=V_{1}\otimes V_{2}$. Define the tensor product arrangement $(A_{1}\otimes A_{2},V)$ by
$$A_{1}\otimes A_{2}=\{H_{1}\otimes V_{2}+V_{1}\otimes H_{2}|H_{i}\in A_{i} \}.$$

Obviously, $dim (H_{1}\otimes V_{2}+V_{1}\otimes H_{2})=dim V_{1} dim V_{2} -1$.

What can we say about characteristic polynomial of $(A_{1}\otimes A_{2},V)$?

Let $(A_{1},V_{1})$ and $(A_{2},V_{2})$ be graphic arrangements. I think $(A_{1}\otimes A_{2},V)$ is also graphic. Is it true?

Comment: Is it not the case that the intersection lattice of $A_1 \otimes A_2$ is the product of the lattices for $A_1$ and $A_2$?

Comment: Not sure. Can you explain more?

Comment: The intersection lattice of $A_1\oplus A_2$ is the cartesian product of lattices for $A_1$ and $A_2$, where $A_1\oplus A_2$ is the natural construction of an arrangement in $V_1\oplus V_2$.

Comment: @SamHopkins: I fear this isn't true, or at least I don't see why it is. It is not generally true that $\left(U\otimes B + A\otimes V\right) \cap \left(X\otimes B + A\otimes Y\right) = \left(U\cap X\right)\otimes B + A\otimes\left(V\cap Y\right)$ for vector spaces $A$ and $B$ and subspaces $U$ and $X$ of $A$ and subspaces $V$ and $Y$ of $B$.

Comment: To address the original question: Yes, if $\left (A_1,V_1\right) $ and $\left (A_2,V_2\right) $ are graphic, then so is $\left ( A_1\otimes A_2, V\right) $.